# Storing info bytes in ATmega169PA that remain after reprogramming

Tags: avr, atmega, programming, atmel

Does anyone know if there is a way that I can store 2 bytes of data into an ATmega169PA that will survive re-programming of the device? I would like to store a unique ID into an ATmega169PA that will remain in the device even if I erase both FLASH and EEPROM or reprogram the device with a new application.

Comment: I'm curious: Why?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this absolutely without resorting to an external storage device, but it's likely that chip has an ability to semi-protect a portion of the flash for a bootloader, which could help you a little, but probably not provide as much protection as you are looking for.

Comment: Some of the AVR chips have what is called a userpage of the flash memory which does not get erased on flashing, but this chip does not appear to be one of them.

Comment: You know that you can set a fuse on the chip that tells the programmer not to erase EEPROM on reprogramming, right?  Otherwise you are talking about write-once read-only memory, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you're just talking about a bare chip, there isn't much point in retaining a unique ID if you're completely reprogramming the chip anyway. If you really want to do this, then putting a sticker on the top of the chip is probably the most direct approach.

However, if the chip is part of a larger assembly, and you want to keep track of specific assemblies, products like the [DS2401 Silicon Serial Number](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2903) are made for this purpose.